# Select a value in dropdown using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('select[name^="salesrep"] option[value="Bruce Jones"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

How do I write above piece of code in javascript?

Comment: What browsers do you need to target?

Comment: please explain your question with relevent codes and explanation

Comment: `var yourelement = document.getElementsByName('salesrep');
yourelement.value = "valueToSelect;";`

Comment: @manikantgautam Please read the question again (:

Comment: @Reshma      I am having a input text field[name="iTextField"] .In onchange event of the particular field i am calling a function in which i need to make an option of drop down get selected

Answer (score 2):

You can use querySelector as below

```js
document.querySelector('select[name^="salesrep"] option[value="Bruce Jones"]').selected = true;
```

```html
<select name="salesrep">
<option value="Bruce Jones">Bruce Jones</option>
<option value="John Doo">John Doo</option>
<option value="John Lee">John Lee</option>
<option value="Jane Doo">Jane Doo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can i make option text get selected like

Comment: document.querySelector('select[name^="salesrep"] option[text="Bruce Jones"]').selected = true;

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```js
var mySelect = document.getElementById('salesrep');
for(var i, j = 0; i = mySelect.options[j]; j++) {
    if(i.value == 'Bruce Jones') {
        mySelect.selectedIndex = j;
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="salesrep" id="salesrep">
<option value="Bruce Jones">Bruce Jones</option>
<option value="John Doo">John Doo</option>
<option value="John Lee">John Lee</option>
<option value="Jane Doo">Jane Doo</option>
</select>
```